# How to extend the sections of sheaf restricted on a closed scheme to the whole scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here is my question:

> Let $B$ be a connected algebraic scheme over some field $k$. Let $i:X\subset B$ be a closed subscheme. Pick a coherent sheaf (or vector bundle if you like) $\mathscr{F}$ of $B$. Is there **some cohomology condition of $i^*\mathscr{F}$** such that any global section of $i^*\mathscr{F}$ can extend to a global section of $\mathscr{F}$, that is,
> $H^0(B,\mathscr{F})\to H^0(X,i^*\mathscr{F})$ is surjective? If not, is there some special case so that this is right?

Let $j:B\backslash X\to B$, we have the canonical exact sequence: $$0\to j_!j^*\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F}\to i_*i^*\mathscr{F}\to0.$$
Hence we know that if $H^1(B,j_!j^*\mathscr{F})=0$, then well done. But how about the conditions of $i_*i^*\mathscr{F}$? If $H^1(X,i^*\mathscr{F})=0$, can we have the same conclusion?

Here is the original question from D. Eisenbud and J. Harris's book *3264 and all that* in Page 496:

> Let $B$ be a connected scheme and $\mathscr{E}$ be a rank $2$ vector bundle over $B\times\mathbb{P}^1$ such that for some closed point $b\in B$ we have $\mathscr{E}|_{\{b\}\times\mathbb{P}^1}\cong\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n)$ for some $n>0$. Then since $H^1(\mathscr{E}|_{\{b\}\times\mathbb{P}^1})=0$, the section $(1,0)$ of it can extends to a nowhere-zero section of $\mathscr{E}$ in a neighborhood of $\{b\}\times\mathbb{P}^1$. Why?

This might be a stupid question but I really want to know why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an argument using cohomology and base-change/semicontinuity. Let $ \pi : B \times \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow B $ be the projection.

Since $ H^1( \mathbb{P}^1_b, \mathcal{E}|_{\mathbb{P}^1_b}) = 0 $ we get by cohomology and base-change that $ R^1\pi_* \mathcal{E} \otimes k(b) = 0 $ and because $ R^1 \pi_* \mathcal{E} $ is coherent, Nakayama's lemma shows that $ R^1 \pi_* \mathcal{E} $ is $ 0 $ on a neighbourhood $ U $ of $ b $ (This could also have been obtained by semicontinuity but it is the same argument). In particular $ R^1 \pi_* \mathcal{E} $ is locally free on $ U $ so by cohomology and base-change we get that $ \pi_* \mathcal{E} \otimes k(a) \rightarrow H^0( \mathbb{P}^1_a, \mathcal{E}|_{\mathbb{P}^1_a}) $ is an isomorphism for every $ a \in U $, in particular also for $ b $, which shows that any section extends locally, say on $ V \times \mathbb{P}^1_b $. This gives Eisenbud's statement - the section is nonvanishing on the fiber so you can shrink $ V $ so that the extended section remains non vanishing and that's your tubular neighbourhood.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems like I'm thinking in the wrong direction.